# Label Pie/Dougnhut Chart in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I'm generating Doughnut chart, but the line label percentage is off in some cases and the percent symbol is off in some cases as well.

[image: Donut Charts]

How do I solve this?

--
Code

```
        chart.Series["Data"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Doughnut;
        chart.Series["Data"]["PieLineColor"] = "LightGray";
        chart.Series["Data"]["DoughnutRadius"] = "30";
        chart.Series["Data"]["PieStartAngle"] = "270";
        chart.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.Height = 90;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.Width = 90;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Inclination = 0;
        chart.Series["Data"].Label = "#PERCENT{P0}";
        chart.Series["Data"].LegendText = "#VALX";
        chart.Series["Data"].Font = new Font("Arial", 16.0f,    FontStyle.Bold);
```

Comment: What Thomas is trying to say is, please show us the code that created the charts, so that we can actually have a chance of helping you solve your problem. You can read about a [mcve] to get a better idea of what will help others help you.

Comment: add code in question

Answer (score 0):

```
Html code:   
  <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="400px"  >
            <Titles>
                <asp:Title ShadowOffset="3" Name="Items" />
            </Titles>
            <Legends>
                <asp:Legend Alignment="Center" Docking="Bottom" IsTextAutoFit="False" Name="Default" 
                    LegendStyle="Row"  />
            </Legends>
            <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Data" Color="Chocolate" BackGradientStyle="HorizontalCenter"   />
            </Series>
            <ChartAreas >
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"  BorderWidth="0" BackColor="White"   />
            </ChartAreas>
        </asp:Chart> 

    Code behind:
    chart.Series["Data"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Doughnut;
    chart.Series["Data"]["PieLabelStyle"] = "outside";
    chart.Series["Data"]["PieLineColor"] = "LightGray";
    chart.Series["Data"]["DoughnutRadius"] = "30";
    chart.Series["Data"]["PieStartAngle"] = "270";
    chart.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.Height = 90;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.Width = 90;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Inclination = 0;
    chart.Series["Data"].Font = new Font("Arial", 16.0f,    FontStyle.Bold);
    foreach (DataPoint p in chart.Series["Data"].Points)
                    {
                        p.Label = "#PERCENT";
                        p.LabelToolTip = "#VALX";
                        p.LabelForeColor = Color.Brown;
                        p.LegendText = "#VALX";
                        p.LegendToolTip = "#PERCENT";
                        p.LabelToolTip = "#PERCENT\n#VALX";

                    }
```

Only add foreach loop below to the your current .cs code
This will add label and  tooltiop both to your Pie/Dougnhut chart.
Please let me know if you will face any of the issue while doing this.

Comment: you can use '#VALX' for x axis values as label
OR
you can use '#VALY' for y axis values as label

Comment: thanks for the help, my problem now is the label line that is outside the area, I would like her to be visible whole

Comment: Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
Chart1.Series[0]["PieLabelStyle"] = "outside";
Chart1.Series[0]["PieStartAngle"] = "90";

Comment: above mentioned code PieLabelStyle = outside will display label outside as per requirement.

Comment: Please let me know if you will face any other issue, if resolved please verify and thumbs up to answer.

Comment: The percentage is ok. But the line is erased, as shown in the picture. I want the image is fully visible